# Able to cause non-injective account associations between sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, openid, linked-accounts

It's possible to have two accounts on one site linked to the same account on another site, if the two accounts on the first site have two different OpenIDs and the account on the second site has both of those OpenIDs associated with it. For example, I made [620481](https://stackoverflow.com/users/620481/user620481) on SO. It has two OpenIDs, http://test1.mrozekma.com/ and http://test2.mrozekma.com/. I then registered [4833](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4833/user4833) on Unix with OpenID http://test1.mrozekma.com/ (which caused it to automatically associate with SO), and [4834](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4834/user4834) with OpenID http://test2.mrozekma.com/ (which also triggered an association with the same SO account). Both accounts show 620481 in their accounts tab as the linked SO account; SO shows 4833 as the UL account (presumably because it was associated first).

---

It's still a little unclear what problems this can cause; it was found in the wild on [this PSE post](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1187/help-someone-please-help-me-merge-my-accounts)

Comment: I'm wracking my brain trying to figure out how this could be used to benefit my five thousand sock puppet accounts, and I'm coming up blank.

Comment: @Pollyanna, sadly, associating to two different accounts does not give the +100 boost twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the account system overhauls over a year ago - this is no longer possible.  A unique key constraint in the global accounts database solves that one pretty well, even in a code race situation :)